# Jpa query for both postgis and h2gis

Tags: hibernate, jpa, h2, postgis

I have queries in JpaRepository which use Postgis functions like ST_MakeEnvelope,ST_DWithin etc. That's for production code.

I also want test these queries for H2gis, but these functions wont work then.

How can I bridge this gap with hibernate spatial?

My query is as:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Feature f WHERE geometry && ST_MakeEnvelope(:west, :south, :east, :north, :srid)", nativeQuery = true)
```

How to make it work with h2 gis too?

So I created this query:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Feature f where dwithin(f.geometry, :centre, :range)", nativeQuery = true)
```

But this throws error:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Function "DWITHIN" not found;
```

I have following dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.197</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.orbisgis</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2gis-functions</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.17.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Are you intialize h2 db for spatial ?

Comment: Yes, my save operations are working fine, and read as well. Problem is only when read queries have spatial functions used.

Comment: Can you try with `ST_DWithin` instead `dwithin`

Comment: Tried that. That too throws same error.

Comment: I mean h2 gis extension function initialized ? Like _CREATE ALIAS IF NOT EXISTS H2GIS_SPATIAL FOR "org.h2gis.functions.factory.H2GISFunctions.load";
CALL H2GIS_SPATIAL();_

Comment: yup , jut did it and then got some issue related to:Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Feature not supported: "converting to class com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry";

Comment: Would need to update h2gis version it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the H2GIS latest version. In the latest version [this](https://github.com/orbisgis/h2gis/issues/891) issue is fixed.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.orbisgis</groupId>
   <artifactId>h2gis</artifactId>
   <version>1.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

You need to initialize the H2GIS extension

From [doc](https://github.com/orbisgis/h2gis): 
To initialize the H2GIS extension apply the SQL syntax:

```
CREATE ALIAS IF NOT EXISTS H2GIS_SPATIAL FOR "org.h2gis.functions.factory.H2GISFunctions.load";
CALL H2GIS_SPATIAL();
```

Then use like

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Feature f where ST_DWithin(f.geometry, :centre, :range)", nativeQuery = true)
```

Comment: this dependency is not found

Comment: http://www.h2gis.org/news/releases/...on this page dependencies are provided, but it seems they are either not available or are not compatible.

Comment: and what is your dependency for org.locationtech.jts?

Comment: You are using `com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry` right ?

Comment: org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry

Comment: That is not mentioned in the question not in dependency so I thought differently

Comment: latest hibernate spatial uses locationtech jts.

Comment: Then use H2GIS 1.5.0 as I am attached in answer

Comment: H2GIS1.5.0 gives me error: CoordinateXYZM class not found

Comment: Jts replaced on that version only

Comment: Actually its a 2 pronged issue for me. I use postgres for normal application mode, and h2 for unit tests. What I observe is that when I update h2gis to 1.5.0, my main  application also starts failing unexpectedly with java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.locationtech.jts.geom.CoordinateXY . It should not as I have configured h2 only for tests. And with lower h2gis, application works but tests fail.

Comment: I think that's different problem now, your current problem solved but it's chaining and atlast XY problem

Comment: I have the same issue as Mandroi, using postgis (gres) and h2 but when using H2, just will not execute queries with geography in them such as ST_Area. However, I am using vivd's libraries.